# Background not filling the whole mobile view

Tags: css, mobile

I want to get the background to be dynamic, proportionally re-size, and fill in the whole background instead of simply covering half of it like it is now on any mobile platform.

I'm an absolute novice at web design and am going through a merchant website. I thought I had figured out my website, but I completely forgot about mobile views so it is a mess in that area. I have tried media queries, viewport things, and more to no avail, so I feel like there was something default preventing them from working.

Website: http://www.reliefinsleep.com/

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size: cover;` will achive what you are looking for. This stretches the bg image to the size of the viewport cropping the edges rather that squashing it.

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) { /* max-width would be the breakpoint for when this style kicks in */
  body {
    background-size: cover; /* stretches to size of viewport */
    background-position: center; /* center the bg image */
  }
}
```

You can also use percentage, pixel and em values for the `background-size` property. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: This works, however, I should've been more specific. I'm not concerned about the width, as it fits perfectly, I am trying to get the background to expand its height to fit the entire screen in that aspect, seeing as it is only filling half the screen on mobile screens.